# When I am trying to decrypt getting following error

Tags: java

I am getting following error while decrypting.

Once it was working fine but suddenly I am getting this error.

How can I solve this problem?
I have read many articles but couldn't get help.

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:388)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(AESCipher.java:186)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:786)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:848)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1212)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1152)
at 
com.test.security.TestEncryptDecrypt.decrypt(TestEncryptDecrypt.java:92)
at com.test.security.TestEncryptDecrypt.main(TestEncryptDecrypt.java:59)
```

The code is give below:

```
public static void main(String []args){

try {

String encString =  encrypt("PID=0000000003|ITC=NA|PRN=MNKB0701511135|AMT=1.00|CRN=INR|RU=https://www.testsite.com/testsk/servlet/TestResponseHandler?");

System.out.println("Enc  : " + encString);

System.out.println("Dec  : "+ decrypt(encString));

} catch (Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Encrypt method

```
public static String encrypt(String data) throws Exception {
String keyFile = "E:\\testpath\\Keys\\0000000003.key";
byte[] keyb = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(keyFile));

SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(keyb, "AES");
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(data.getBytes());
return new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
}
```

Decrypt method

```
public static String decrypt(String encryptedData)
throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
NoSuchPaddingException, IOException {

String keyFile = "E:\\testpath\\Keys\\0000000003.key";

byte[] keyb = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(keyFile));

SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(keyb, "AES");    
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);

byte[] decordedValue = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedData.getBytes());
byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
return new String(decValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you are missing a parameter in the init methods. If you're using CBC you should also specify the `AlgorithmParameterSpec`.

Could you perhaps try the following:

```
byte[] paramSpecBytes = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
IvParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(paramSpecBytes);
```

And in your encrypt and decrypt methods:

```
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey, paramSpec);
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, paramSpec);
```

You could fill the bytes with any value you like though, doesn't need to be zero's. Best would be some random value.